# How to get VLC to correctly read the path?

Tags: bash, vlc

So I love the show *The Office*. I made a bash script that gets all the show's paths and stores them in a file, then another script randomly picks a link and runs it on VLC like so:

```
vlc "$link"
```

When I run `echo $link` I get this:

```
'/media/mohamed/Storage/smithers-storage/Shows/Organized shows/The Office/The Office US Season 9 [HDTV]/The.Office.US.S09E06.HDTV.x264-LOL.[VTV].mp4'
```

which is the correct path!

When I run:

```
vlc '/media/mohamed/Storage/smithers-storage/Shows/Organized shows/The Office/The Office US Season 9 [HDTV]/The.Office.US.S09E06.HDTV.x264-LOL.[VTV].mp4'
```

it opens the video successfully but when using `vlc "$link"`, VLC reads the path incorrectly and throws the following error:

```
[00007fe248001ae0] filesystem stream error: cannot open file /home/mohamed/.FunStore/'/media/mohamed/Storage/smithers-storage/Shows/Organized shows/The Office/The Office Season 3 DvDrip-McTav/The Office [3.22] Beach Games.avi' (No such file or directory)
```

For some reason, the path VLC receives always starts from the current directory and fails to open the file completely.

Comment: it reads the filename correctly however it starts from home directory as in the last example.

Comment: it says (No such file or directory) are you sure that path or name of the file is correct?

Comment: try to drag and drop the file

Comment: When you using the quote `vlc "$link"` ,that's mean you just call the path of file instead the file. Try without a quote

Comment: I did use it without them and it just splits everything up

Comment: Try: `vlc "file://$link"`

Comment: Please edit your post to including the output of `ps auxf |grep vlc`

Answer (score 0):

Use `export $link` after you assign the string value/path.

Comment: or `export link='/media/mohamed/Storage/smithers-storage/Shows/Organized shows/The Office/The Office US Season 9 [HDTV]/The.Office.US.S09E06.HDTV.x264-LOL.[VTV].mp4'`. However, can you [edit] your answer to explain why `export` is required?

Comment: Regardless, the issue (in this case) *seems to be* the start of the path: `/media/mohamed/...` vs. `/home/mohamed/...`